# Where should I save the access token value shared by multiple sessions in php?

Tags: php, singleton, access-token, superglobals

You are about to send an email using the outgoing email api. At this time, access_token only needs to be acquired once, so I want to run the authentication process once and share it in several sessions without renewing the key until the key expires. Usually, if you save it to a database or to a file, you will be able to access it anywhere within php of the Apache web server. However, I would like to ask you how about saving it in a better place than saving it in this database or file. For example, isn't it a good idea to store it in php's super global variable?

```
if($_GLOABLS['token'] != null) 
    $_GLOABLS['token'] = access_token;
```

Comment: _"isn't it a good idea to store it in php's super global variable?"_ - those live only as long, as the current script instance is running. Script ends - all globals are gone as well.

Comment: Why do you think a database isn't a good place? What problem are you having?

Comment: Did the answer below help ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Mr Rohit Gupta: The answer below was very helpful. We are going to discuss this issue with our colleagues who work with us, and all of our team members are very grateful for your professional opinion.

Comment: Great. do you mind ticking it etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another place where you can store some information is the environment.  I wouldn't put loads of variables there, but a few is fine.

I actually use it for a few variables that are different between production and development.  This way, the source files can be identical.

If you have access to the **php.ini** files then you can store it in there.

If you are using apache and have access to **.htaccess** file, then you can store like this

```
setenv My_Variable value
```

If you are using xampp, then you can place it in **F:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf**

```
SetEnv PHP_DEBUG 1
```

And you can read it in your php as

```php
$MyVariable   = getenv('My_Variable');     
$Debug = (getenv('PHP_DEBUG'));
```